# Racket reader macros

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme, racket

Is there any way to make simple reader macros in Racket. I mean a generalization like this:

```
(define-reader-syntax "'" quote)
; finds expressions that start with "'" and wraps them in `(quote ...)`
'(foo) ; => (quote (foo))
'foo ; => (quote foo)
```

I used a built in syntax to make clear what I mean. One of the things I'd like to use this for is replicating clojure's shorthand lambda `(#(+ 1 %) 5) ; => 6`

It seems like it would be very easy to just define a "shorthand-lambda" macro and map the "#" prefix to that.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at the code for [afl](https://github.com/AlexKnauth/afl) or [curly-fn](https://github.com/lexi-lambda/racket-curly-fn), both of which define full implementations of reader extensions for shorthand lambda expressions.

Answer (score 17):

Here's how to implement your shorthand lambda:

```
#lang racket

(define rt (make-readtable #f #\# 'non-terminating-macro
                           (λ (c in . _)
                             (define body (read in))
                             `(lambda (%) ,body))))
(parameterize ([current-readtable rt]
               [current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
  (eval (read (open-input-string "(#(+ 1 %) 5)")))) ;; => 6
```

Here's how to implement your simpler example, making `&` be equivalent to `'`:

```
(define rt2 (make-readtable #f #\& #\' #f))

(parameterize ([current-readtable rt2]
               [current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
  (eval (read (open-input-string "&(3 4 5)")))) ;; => '(3 4 5)
```

Comment: In `(λ (c in . _)` from the first example, what is `c`?

Comment: It's the character that triggered the reader macro, in this case always `#\#`.  See the documentation for [`make-readtable`](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/reference/readtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-readtable%29%29).

Answer (score 7):

Look at the guide entry on [readtables](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-reader.html#(part._readtable)) and [reader extensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-reader.html) to see how to do this. This [reference section](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reader_Extension.html) is useful too. Readtable extensions are a bit more complicated than your example, but they are very powerful.

For your specific problem, [SRFI-26](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-26.html) provides a similar syntax for Scheme and Sam Tobin-Hochstadt wrote a [fancy app](https://github.com/samth/fancy-app) Racket macro that implements Scala's take on this.